# I am unable to filter XPage view source using search in XPiNC

Tags: xpages, xpinc

I have built a simple XPage to display a Notes view. Everything works fine, and the view is rendered perfectly.

As soon as I configure a 'search' parameter for the view, however, I receive the error: "Error 500: Unexpected error condition". This can be any search parameter - a simple word or a syntactically correct FT search query.

Yes, the database has been indexed, and FT searches work perfectly using the normal Lotus Notes views.

This only produces an error when I view the XPage using XPiNC (this is a hybrid app for use with Lotus Notes clients). The error occurs whether I open the database locally or on the server. The searches I am executing should definitely return results.

Is there a limitation to using view data sources in XPages with XPiNC?
Any suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Can you post a code snippet of your view? It works in my case and code looks something like this `<xp:viewPanel....><xp:this.data><xp:dominoView var="view1" viewName="ByName" search="Text to Search"></xp:dominoView></xp:this.data>...</xp:viewPanel>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does the runtime error say? Please check the XPages log files in the IBM_Technical_Support folder in the data directory.

If you can not get to the XPages log files on the server directly, then use [XPages Log File Reader from OpenNTF](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?name=XPages%20Log%20File%20Reader) to get easy access to the log files from a browser.

Comment: Thanks very much Per! Yep... I totally forgot about the xpages.log file. When I checked the local log file, it indicated that "com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: The design of column XXXX does not provide for sorting the view as requested.".

Comment: I had the column configured to sort ascending when the column header is clicked, but I needed to change that to sort in both directions. Once I made the change, the error disappeared.

I'm not seeing consistent search results though. I am going to have to read the doco again, because I don't remember having to set these parameters to effectively search before.